# weird problem with select count from multiple tables (with joins)

Tags: mysql, join, count

I'm having an odd problem with the following query, it works all correct,
the count part in it gets me the number of comments on a given 'hintout'

I'm trying to add a similar count that gets the number of 'votes' for each hintout, the below is the query:

```
SELECT h.*
  , h.permalink AS hintout_permalink
  , hi.hinter_name
  , hi.permalink
  , hf.user_id AS followed_hid
  , ci.city_id, ci.city_name, co.country_id, co.country_name, ht.thank_id
  , COUNT(hc.comment_id) AS commentsCount 
FROM hintouts AS h 
INNER JOIN hinter_follows AS hf ON h.hinter_id = hf.hinter_id 
INNER JOIN hinters AS hi ON h.hinter_id = hi.hinter_id 
LEFT JOIN cities AS ci ON h.city_id = ci.city_id 
LEFT JOIN countries as co ON h.country_id = co.country_id 
LEFT JOIN hintout_thanks AS ht ON (h.hintout_id = ht.hintout_id 
  AND ht.thanker_user_id = 1)
LEFT JOIN hintout_comments AS hc ON hc.hintout_id = h.hintout_id 
WHERE hf.user_id = 1 
GROUP BY h.hintout_id
```

I tried to add the following to the select part:

```
COUNT(ht2.thanks_id) AS thanksCount
```

and the following on the join:

```
LEFT JOIN hintout_thanks AS ht2 ON h.hintout_id = ht2.hintout_id
```

but the weird thing happening, to which I could not find any answers or solutions,
is that the moment I add this addtiional part, the count for comments get ruined (I get wrong and weird numbers), and I get the same number for the thanks -
I couldn't understand why or how to fix it...and I'm avoiding using nested queries

so any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

ps: this might have been posted twice, but I can't find the previous post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add

```
LEFT JOIN hintout_thanks AS ht2 ON h.hintout_id = ht2.hintout_id
```

The number of rows increases, you get duplicate rows for table `hc`, which get counted double in `COUNT(hc.comment_id)`.
You can replace

```
COUNT(hc.comment_id) <<-- counts duplicated
/*with*/ 
COUNT(DISTINCT(hc.comment_id))  <<-- only counts unique ids
```

To only count unique appearances on an id.

On values that are not unique, like `co.county_name` the `count(distinct` will not work because it will only list the distinct countries (if all your results are in the USA, the count will be 1).

**Quassnoi**
Has solved the whole count problem by putting the counts in a sub-select so that the extra rows caused by all those joins do not influence those counts.

Comment: aha i see,
is a sub select a good idea or is it better to find a way using joins or distinct, or I don't know what other methods there are...?

Comment: @roy naufal, both have their place. I always go for the `join` + `distinct` route first, and if that's too slow I try a sub-select and see if that's faster. You need to time the code and test it to see which is better.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  h.*, h.permalink AS hintout_permalink, hi.hinter_name,
        hi.permalink, hf.user_id AS followed_hid,
        ci.city_id, ci.city_name, co.country_id, co.country_name,
        ht.thank_id,
        COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    hintout_comments hci
        WHERE   hc.hintout_id = h.hintout_id
        ), 0) AS commentsCount,
        COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    hintout_comments hti
        WHERE   hti.hintout_id = h.hintout_id
        ), 0) AS thanksCount
FROM    hintouts AS h 
JOIN    hinter_follows AS hf
ON      hf.hinter_id = h.hinter_id
JOIN    hinters AS hi
ON      hi.hinter_id = h.hinter_id
LEFT JOIN
        cities AS ci
ON      ci.city_id = h.city_id
LEFT JOIN
        countries as co
ON      co.country_id = h.country_id
LEFT JOIN
        hintout_thanks AS ht
ON      ht.hintout_id = h.hintout_id
        AND ht.thanker_user_id=1 
WHERE   hf.user_id = 1
```